# Looking for Features in WP Compatible Slider

Tags: plugins

a friend and I are working on a client website and they want an extremely feature rich slider but we haven't found one that does everything we're asking. Does anyone have suggestions?

1. Needs to have the ability to be randomized so a different set of slides shows each page load
2. Needs the ability to open a modal from a button click on each slide
3. They have over 400 slides they want loaded so we're also looking for a way to feed into a slider that creates slides based on a csv or XML or similar file

If we can't find something already made we'll have to do some custom coding but trying to avoid this option if possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.